# How to show dom element size in Microsoft Edge / IE developer tool?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

In the DOM Inspector for Chrome and Firefox when hover over a DOM element we get something like this that indicates the width / height of the element

[image]

Is this feature available in Microsoft Edge, or IE, and if so how to enable or access it?

Answer (score 5):

This feature is available in both Microsoft Edge, and Internet Explorer. You can toggle the highlighting with Ctrl+Shift+I (or click the icon at the top-left of the DOM Explorer).

For the dimensions of an element, select the Layout panel on the right.

Further Reading: [F12 devtools guide: DOM Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/f12-devtools-guide/dom-explorer/)

[image]